Clarification for understanding matter fundamentally
I am entering my undergrad second year (so I have no formal quantum physics education) and have been stuck on conceptualizing matter at its core on a day to day basis. I've always envisioned matter as nothing more than some complicated form energy (which I look forward to studying in depth), which resists movement / change of any property really (which varies based on the material, which I would describe as a specific interaction of the "matter energy"); however, clearly, this description of matter is ridiculously loose, and doesn't really hold much value nor information; quite frankly its hard to even call it a description at all. I was wondering if there is any mathematical model I should look into to understand matter fundamentally, rather than: the open ended description I have come up with, or the simple quark, electron, proton, neutron model I was taught in Highschool and university chemistry (My issue with the latter description is the dimensionless of fundamental particles, leading me to believe they are nothing more than some form of energy with a certain "Signature").

This might help you understand what energy is - How is energy "stored in an electric field"?

Dependence of molar heat capacity on absolute temperature for various solids can give a good understanding of matter.
For a mathematical example, Debye model is used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model
